# Question whether we need transit visas for stopover in Istanbul with no exit from airport

Tags: turkey, transit-visas, cameroonian-citizens

I am a Cameroonian national with the UN Laissez-Passer traveling with my family of 4 (wife and 3 kids with Cameroon passports) from Phnom Penh, Cambodia, to my final destination, Yaounde, Cameroon and transitting through Istanbul on a Turkish Airlines flight. Do we need transit visas?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not planning to leave the Air-side part of the airport, you do not need a visa.

Source: Connected via Istanbul a couple of times. Never needed a visa as long as I stayed in the airport